# Assign Shortcut keys within the VBE Window

Tags: vba, excel

From the Excel Window, I can assign a shortcut key to my macro by:

1. going to the Developer tab
2. touching the **Macros** button
3. touching **Options...** in the resulting Dialog Box

[image]

Can I assign this from within the VBE Window, using the VBE menu bar instead??

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for (so I'm posting it as a comment), but the best I can come up with is a some code setting the Application.OnKey to execute when a defined key press is done.  Would that work, or do you want a menu option specifically?

Comment: @sous2817 Post it as an answer and I will upvote it at a minimum.....as a workaround...it is O.K.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to do it using VBA you can do something like:

```
Sub SetShortcutKeys()
With Application
    .OnKey Key:="^+K", Procedure:="YourMacroGoesHere"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly I get a different a different dialog box using **VBE,** but OnKey works just fine!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent doh, you're right!  I'll take that bit out.  Sorry, looked to fast w/o checking.

Answer (score 4):

The `Application.OnKey` approach keeps the shortcut separate from the procedure (which makes maintenance difficult), and you might end up with conflicts - particularly if you've assigned keys using the Macros dialog *and* the `Application.OnKey` property. And, of course, you need the `SetShortCutKeys` code to run on workbook_open, which might not always run.

Fortunately, it *is possible* to assign the shortcut key in VBA, and within the procedure itself, but you'll need to export the module, edit the text file, and then reimport. Unfortunately, while VBA does maintain the code, the shortcut keys only seem to work in Excel. Perhaps it's a feature of VBA that the host application can optionally support.

Let's say you have the following VBA in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Bar()
  MsgBox "Bar"
End Sub
```

If you use the Macros dialog in Excel, and choose a shortcut key for the `Bar` macro to `Ctrl+Shift+T`, and then Export the module to a text file, you'll find the module source is:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Option Explicit

Sub Bar()
Attribute Bar.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "T\n14"
  MsgBox "Bar"
End Sub
```

Notice the `Attribute Bar.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "T\n14"` attribute, which wasn't visible in the VBIDE, but is persisted by VBA in the underlying source.  The `T` in `T\n14` is a case-sensitive key (which *implies* a `Shift`), and *I think* the `\n14` must refer to the `Ctrl` key. By following the VB Attribute naming pattern and syntax, and including similar lines in your other procedures, you can assign shortcut keys in other procedures using the text editor, and then, when you're done, you can import the modified module back into the VBA project.

Note that once you import the modified module, you'll no longer be able to *see* the attribute lines, and you'll need to take care not to change the name or number of parameters in the procedure, as the VBIDE *might* delete the underlying attribute without warning you.

Comment: This is an extremely interesting idea! I also appreciate your taking the time to re-visit this issue ...........................I will certainly give this a try!

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.excelbanter.com/excel-programming/285034-what-vb_invoke_func-attribute.html), \n14 refers to "user functions", as would \n3 refer to "Math & Trig".